# Functions.php javascript code will not update

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am using the following on functions.php within wordpress to load java only on specific pages

```
function load_js_assets1() {
    if( is_page( 'A6 (Dove Holes)' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script('newa6dove.js', '{path}', array('jquery'), '', false);
    } 
}
```

The javascript returned on the page itself does not seem to change when I update the newa6dove.js javascript file specified. The javascript that is specified also calls a JSON api, which does not seem to update on the site either following this functions.php integration.

How can this be set up so that each time the page is loaded this code on the functions.php loads a fresh, updated version of the .js file? Seems like it's sticking to the version used when the .js file was initially uploaded.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you set the path of the JS properly? If you look at the [docs here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) you will see the first parameter is just a handle and the second param has to be the correct path to that script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add version to javascript file.
This should work.

```php
function load_js_assets1() {
    if( is_page( 'A6 (Dove Holes)' ) ) {
        $datetime = new DateTime('now');
        $revision = $datetime->format("YmdHis"); // number of version/revision of js
        wp_enqueue_script('newa6dove.js?'.$revision, '{path}', array('jquery'), '', false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution is cool but you can move the `$revision` to the 4th parameter of `wp_enqueue_script` then it's will look more elegant.

`wp_enqueue_script('newa6dove.js', '{path}', array('jquery'), $revision, false);`